# Mock object without fields and methods

Tags: python

I have for example:

```
class City:
    field = "bbb"

    def __init__(self):
        some_action()

    def street(self):
        return "aaa"
```

Is possible to mock City object and still use street method as in other programming languages?

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
from unittest.mock import patch

@patch("classes.City")
def test_city(city):
    assert city.street() = "aaa"
    assert city.field = "bbb"
```

In short, I would like to mock the entire object so that it does not execute the constructor and that all fields and methods in the object work as before.

Comment: Mock `some_action` to do nothing?

Comment: Rule #1 when using mocks: don't test the mock. And your example doesn't need any mock of the class at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need everything else to occur but `some_action`, mock *it* to do nothing.

(`so73635578` happens to be the name of this module. You'd replace it with wherever `destroy_universe` actually is.)

```
from unittest import mock


def destroy_universe():
    raise ZeroDivisionError("Oh no, you did it again.")


class City:
    field = "bbb"

    def __init__(self):
        destroy_universe()

    def street(self):
        return "aaa"

def test_city():
    with mock.patch('so73635578.destroy_universe'):
        city = City()
        assert city.street() == "aaa"
        assert city.field == "bbb"
```

To wit:

```
$ py.test -v so73635578.py
platform darwin -- Python 3.10.6, pytest-7.1.3, pluggy-1.0.0 -- /Users/akx/envs/so-misc/bin/python
cachedir: .pytest_cache
rootdir: /Users/akx/build/so-misc
plugins: anyio-3.6.1
collected 1 item

so73635578.py::test_city PASSED
```

Comment: Unfortunately, in your example the destroy_universe function is still running and throws an exception.

Comment: @jatkso Then you mocked the wrong thing.

Comment: So how can I do this correctly?

Comment: @jatkso See updated example. Works fine.